# Stripe method won't run from my npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, stripe-payments

I created an npm package and I'm trying to install it in my react app and run a Stripe function from it. But the function that I'm calling from the package isn't initiating, and I'm not sure what the problem is. It just doesn't run, doesn't return any error message, and everything after the line in question doesn't run. Here's what that line in my npm package looks like:

```
const customer = await stripe.customers.search({query: 'email:\'' + email + '\'',})
```

And it's inside an async function called stripeCustomer(email) which is being called from my main function like

```
async function stripeCustomer(email) {
  ...
  const customer = await stripe.customers.search({query: 'email:\'' + email + '\'',}) 
  ...
}

async function main(payload) {
  ...

  var stripeStatus = await stripeCustomer(user.email)

  ...
}
```

When I console.log(stripe) it returns as expected, so I know stripe is being initiated. But the search function doesn't run. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you calling the Search API client-side? If you are, that's probably the problem - the Stripe instance you get client-side is for using Stripe.JS/Elements, not making general calls to Stripe's APIs. These requests should be moved to your backend

Comment: @karbi That makes sense. thanks. Do you have a link tot he docs for what's allowed on the clientside?

Comment: @RushwinJamdas You can collect payment method details client-side or confirm a PaymentIntent. Everything that requires a Secret API key needs to be done server-side